I need help on searching a list of values on pandas Dataframe, and then separating the row the value is found
What im looking to achieve:
I was wondering what would be the best way to find any value of a list in a pandas Dataframe, and then to separate the row where the value is found.
Here is what i Tried
def searchXlsx(xlsx_file: str, numbers: list) -> list:
    
    with open(os.path.realpath(xlsx_file), "rb") as i:
        i = pd.read_excel(i)
        print(i[i.isin(numbers)])

i would like to return the row it is located

I don't understand what you want to do - do you mean return i[i.isin(numbers)] ?

i need to find in wich row any vaue in the numbers list appear and return the entire row

You can use .isin:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

searchvals = np.array([1,45,87,9]) #The values to find

#Create a random dataframe of integers with 100k rows and 10 columns
size = (100000, 10)
columns = [f"col_{x}" for x in range(size[1])]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(low=0, high=1000, size=size), columns=columns)

matches = df.isin(searchvals).any(axis=1) #A series of True/False where each value correspond to a row 

df2 = df.loc[matches] #Extract the matching rows into a new dataframe
df2.head()
#       col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5  col_6  col_7  col_8  col_9
# 34       793    893    435    312    812     87    990    552    496    397
# 47       818    902    478    479    736     83    135     45    180    224
# 55         9    750    118    910    205    866    617    232    506    755
# 94       326    303    868      9    583    310    668    614    720     50
# 99       167    148    586    570    196    473    829     87    266    194

